# jobs -l command fails to write to file using csh

Tags: linux, scripting, redhat, tcsh

We currently have a script where it checks if things are running in the background. It does this by running the following (updated to include a full test script example which I ran on our server):

```
#!/bin/csh -f
sleep 30 &
set testFile = /tmp/checkFile$$
jobs -l > $testFile
```

It prints to the screen the processes running but nothing appears in the check file, thus causing the server to think the other pieces failed to start). At a complete loss on why this doesn't work. Other commands appear to work fine.

I am running rhel 6.8 and running the command as a non-root user. . Running other commands such as `ps > /tmp/testFile` worked without issues.

After further digging on the system, the following notes are added:

- /bin/csh is a softlink to /bin/tcsh (I removed the csh tag)
- Changing the shebang line to /bin/tcsh -f did not change anything (obviously but wanted to state)
- file is created but the contents are empty

Comment: Do you have to use csh?

Comment: Yes i do, word require a massive amount of work to rewrite everything.

Comment: http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt good luck.

Comment: It works for me with both csh and tcsh. Are you sure you're looking at the right file? The name `/tmp/check$$` will include the process ID of the script; if you then look at `/tmp/check$$` from an interactive shell, you're looking at another (likely nonexistent) file. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @KeithThompson I added a tiny bit more code and clarified a couple things. I am not right next to the server but the example should be almost exactly what we have.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't intend `jobs -l` instead of `job -l`?

Comment: So to be clear, this two-line example errors our for you when you run it with `csh file.csh`? (the typo doesn't inspire confidence that you actually ran it on the problematic machine to be honest). Maybe try running it as `csh -f file.csh` to prevent loading startup files?

Comment: No, the example is not almost exactly what you have. For one thing, there will be no jobs running, since the code you've shown us doesn't start any jobs. Again, can you provide a [mcve]? That would include a complete self-contained script, starting with a proper shebang (probably `#!/bin/csh -f`) that we can copy-and-paste and try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @KeithThompson I went ahead and provided a complete example. I showed just the 2 lines that the issue resided in originally to remove any confusion but I guess that just added to it. My apologies, hopefully this example works now.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Added a full example

Comment: Your test program works on my system (Ubuntu 17.04, x86_64). But please add a command to display the actual name of the check file. Is the check file created as an empty file, or is it not created? Do you have tcsh, and is it distinct from csh? If so, does changing `#!/bin/csh -f` to `#!/bin/tcsh -f` have any effect?

Comment: @KeithThompson I believe the issue to be on rhel 6.8 as we did not experience this on rhel 6.5. The file is created but is empty. I changed the test script to #!/bin/tcsh -f and nothing was added to the file. Looking at the system it appears /bin/csh is just a softlink to /bin/tcsh

Comment: You said "It prints to the screen the processes running but nothing appears in the check file". Are you saying that `jobs -l > $testFile` prints to the screen but doesn't print to `$testFile`? I wonder if the `jobs` command is printing to stderr for some reason. Try `jobs -l >& $testFile` to redirect both stdout and stderr.

Comment: @KeithThompson that was the issue! Weird that with 6.8 is starting printing to sterr instead. Do you want to post that as an answer?

Comment: What is the output of `tcsh --version` on RHEL 6.5 and 6.8?

Comment: @KeithThompson RHEL 6.8 reports 6.17.  I will have the 6.5 one later today when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some versions of tcsh, the `jobs -l` command prints its output to stderr. In others it prints to stdout. (I'd say printing to stdout is the correct behavior.)

The workaround is to change

```
jobs -l > $testFile # redirect stdout
```

to

```
jobs -l >& $testFile # redirect both stdout and stderr
```

This should work correctly for any version of tcsh, with or without the bug.

Note that tcsh on the OP's system is a symbolic link to csh, so this is probably specifically a tcsh issue.

There's a mirror of the tcsh sources at https://github.com/tcsh-org/tcsh . The log shows a change made 2016-05-24, "don't print jobs to stderr (paulo.cesar.pereira.de.andrade)". Looking at the commit history, it appears that `jobs` output is printed to stdout in tcsh versions 6.19.01 and 6.20, and to stderr in versions 6.19.00 and earlier. Apparently some packages on the OP's newer RHEL 6.8 system have been updated.

I see `jobs -l` writing to stdout in tcsh 6.14.00 and 6.18.01. It might have been a regression. (I've been unable to build tcsh 6.19 or earlier from source.)

Comment: Kieth,
Thank you very much!. Both rhel 6.5 and rhel 6.8 appear to have version 6.17 installed of tcsh by default. The machine where I stated was running 6.5 had some updated packages on it and thus was not seeing this issue.

Comment: Perhaps you can update the tcsh package on the 6.8 system -- but if you use the `>&` workaround it should work with either the old or the new version. Interestingly, I see the correct behavior (`jobs -l` writing to stdout) on tcsh 6.18.01 and 6.14.00. Perhaps it's a regression.